# migrating from mongodb to postgresql

Tags: django, mongodb, postgresql, django-models

I would like to begin using django, and I have a populated mongo database that I would like to attach to it. I read that django is most frequently used with a postgresql backend. I have roughly 250 documents in the original database and ideally i would like to just populate a new Postgres database with json generated by mongodump.  I have tried for hours to do this with fixtures, but the documents are irregular and they wont interact with the models that I have written for them without causing problems. It seems exceedingly difficult to load from json in this scenario.

Does anyone have any advice about what systems I should use to solve this problem in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: If your documents really are all over the place and you don't have much of a schema then you're in for a world of hurt. I'm sure there are Django-friendly interfaces to MongoDB that you can use.

Comment: it seems that way...

Answer (score 1):

Stripe has a really cool project called [Mosql](https://github.com/stripe/mosql) that we're using for replication a Postgres database. I'm not sure if total migrations are a great use case, but if you can accept a little downtime this seems like it may be a relatively pain free method.

Comment: so it is highly fault tolerant? I've tried this a little bit, but i cant get all my docs to adhere to that one yaml file.

Comment: If you run Mosql with the `--unsafe` option it will ignore irregular documents and continue to replicate